# C++ thread synchronization and cache coherence

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, caching

I was reading about thread synchronization and came to know about as if https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if.

My question is it possible for compiler to rearrange/optimize the below code in a way that it always prints 10 despite of fact that a is modified in main thread.  I have captured a as the const_refrence.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    std::thread t([&b = const_cast<const int&>(a)]{while(true){std::cerr<<b<<std::endl; std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));}});
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    a = 20;
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

For now it works as expected.

Comment: That mostly depends on CPU. And since it is UB, then the answer is "yes, it is possible".

Comment: Your code does NOT modify a in the thread at all

Comment: Looks like a textbook example of a data race (which causes undefined behavior). You say you're reading about synchronization, doesn't your book/tutorial explain that you need synchronization to avoid this kind of UB?

Comment: a isn't even modified in your thread ('a=20` is outside the thread and not protected/datarace here)... so what is your question here? Most of the code just looks like you are trying to break the compiler anyway...

Comment: @PepijnKramer I think the OP asks whether the std::thread that captures `a` by `const &` will or will not see  the change done in the _main_ thread. However as mentioned above there is UB and therefore no guarantee on what can happen.

Comment: The compiler--unless instructed otherwise with a `std::atomic` variable, `std::mutex`, or other sequencing tool--is allowed to assume that if the current thread doesn't change a value, then the value is never changed in any thread.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This question is not about data race, I am only interested about whether change done to a will be visible to thread t or not.

Comment: @wohlstad Thanks that's exactly my question is. I am not sure whether this is a UB or not. 
1) I am casting a non const value to const_ref, so this won't create a UB here.
2) Since thread t is reading from cons ref, so I am thinking can it try to optimize/rearrange code to get the fixed value. To be noted that a is itself not a const.

Comment: @RakeshMehta such a data race causes UB. Once you have UB anything can happen and there's no point trying to rationalize what the result should be.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the reference is const or not. It is UB because one thread writes to `a` and the other reads from it, with nothing to guarantee that it doesn't happen at the same time (the definition of a data race, roughly speaking). The compiler could optimize away repeated reads of `b`. If it doesn't, it's probably because it can't tell that printing and sleeping can't change it.

Comment: holding a constant reference does not imply that the value cannot change. It merely means that the value cannot be modified through that reference.

Answer (score 6):

`a` is not an atomic object and you modify it in one thread while reading it in another without any synchronization between the two.

That's called a data race and the standard declares any such data race undefined behavior.

So the compiler is allowed to do with the code whatever it wants, because undefined behavior means that it doesn't have to guarantee anything about the program's behavior. So yes, always printing `10` is permissible behavior, as is printing `42`.

Whether or not the reference is `const` is immaterial. It doesn't change that one thread is reading and the other thread writing.